# Do the Blue Angels use their #7 aircraft for photography during rehearsal flights?

Tags: airshow, us-navy

I recently had the privilege of watching the Blue Angels fly their rehearsal for an airshow performance, and I noticed that an additional aircraft would often fly a very loose formation with the aircraft in diamond or arrowhead or echelon formation.  It never seemed to join the formation itself, never trailed smoke, and would break off when the main formation split, but then rejoin later to the same loose trail or overhead observation position.  When the team pitched out for landing, it pitched out last, and on landing it was evident that it was the #7 aircraft, which is a 2-seat jet.

The question is, was this aircraft (and presumably, the back-seater in it) capturing photography of the main formation, either as a debriefing tool or for other purposes?  Is this typical for the rehearsal flights?  And if so, how long has this been the norm?

In any event, ***thanks, Navy*** - it was a beautiful show, and the touch of hearing I probably lost to the low pass with full burners, was an entirely worthwhile tradeoff for the goosebumps raised.

Comment: Yes, it might have been a photographer in the back seat. Or a local civilian...politician, press, or other VIP. Also, a potential future team member. The USAF Thunderbirds do the same.

Answer (score 3):

The *Blues* have two specially built F/A-18Fs, #7 and #8 that go along with the team.  They serve a number of functions on the road, including a spare jet should one of F/A-18Es be unavailable for the shows due to maintenance issues, transport for other member of the Blue Angels, media and VIP rides and aerial photography duties.  The USAF Thunderbirds have 2 F-16Ds for a similar purpose as well.